# CSS: Why does "hidden: overflow" disable text underline?

Tags: css

I've got the following text string:

`AEEF8CDB5ADF2F28016F39E1FBFC237DAF98D402`

And since it's pretty long I want to auto-shorten it with CSS using `text-overflow: ellipsis` which works fine.

The problem is: It removes my `text-decoration: underline` but I don't understand why and I want to keep the underline since it's a link.

**NORMAL**

```css
.link {
  font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-position: under;
}

.link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#">AEEF8CDB5ADF2F28016F39E1FBFC237DAF98D402</a>
```

**SHORTENED**

```css
.link {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-position: under;
  max-width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#">AEEF8CDB5ADF2F28016F39E1FBFC237DAF98D402</a>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What you describe doesn't happen in the example snippet you posted...

Comment: it's due to `text-underline-position`

Comment: 1px bottom padding will fix the problem

Comment: What @Bouh said, or 2px for a thicker underline that looks like the first example.

Comment: Thanks y'all, you're right. I added 5px bottom padding and -5px bottom margin so it works now ☺️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your font with additional text-underline = height > line-height.
= overflow. And text-overflow will hide it.
Solution from @Bouh "1px bottom padding will fix the problem"

Comment: Oh, right! Thank you! ❤️ How could I've missed that? I added 5px bottom padding and -5px bottom margin which fixed it (damn text-underline-position!)